# What is reality of Kabir Sagar and other scriptures on Sant Kabir

Tags: vaishnavism, bhakti, gaudiya-vaishnavism, vaishnav, bhakti-mantras

What is Kabir Sagar written by Sant Dharmadas ji which claims that Lord Hanuman and many famous Vaishnav and famous Shaiva saints were initiated by Sant Kabir in some form in and helped them  achieve salvation as Supreme God  and there are some other scriptures also  which are written by Sant Dharmadas ji and Sant Garibdasji dictated by Sant Kabir himself in Satlok which claim Sant Kabir is supreme superior to  all even Tridev it claims. Are these scriptures interpolated ? Pls help me in this regard